# Access Server 2003 formatted HDD from W7 installation

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid1, data-recovery

I have a server problem, not sure what the best approach may be.  The scenario is this:
OS: Server 2003
The OS was on dedicated IDE drive; there are 2x1TB SATA drives which were in a Windows software RAID1, formatted to NTFS.

The dedicated drive crashed, the kind of crash where you can hear rw heads scraping the platter.  Anyhow, what I would like to do is access the data on one of the (intact) SCSI drives via Windows 7.  The drive is hooked up; Win7 can see it as a hardware device, but not as a volume.

I'm trying to avoid the hassle of installing Server 2003 (assuming I can even find a copy) just so I can access the SATA drives, since all I want to do is migrate the data (~800G) to another server (that isn't 8 years old).

Comment: Sorry, but this question is all over the place. Are the drives IDE, SAS, SCSI or SATA. I'll be surprised if you have 1TB SCSI. Do you mean NTFS or FAT32 when you say "Windows native"? And do you mean Windows 7 when you say Windows 2007? How have you 'hooked up' the drive?

Comment: Oh, or did you mean Windows software RAID? If not, what was the RAID controller. What does disk management show? Why doesn't the original server still boot directly if only one of the RAID1 drives failed. Are you SURE it was mirrored RAID?

Comment: Geeze, you're right, I'm short on details.  To be honest I was expecting a 'no' without them :)  The basics are:
The RAID drives are SATA but show under W7 as SCSI

They're formatted NTFS, but no OS on them - that was on a dedicated 

IDE drive which now dines with Odin at his table in Valhalla

The RAID was done using the Server2003 OS, no hardware layer involved

Windows 2007 != Windows 7?  I thought the terms were interchangeable.  Windows OS aren't really my thing...

Comment: Nah, no such thing as Windows 2007! I'm with you a bit more, now and something sounds wrong. Can you let us know exact model / part number of the HDD and the spec of the Windows 7 machines motherboard. If it was a working SATA drive it should just work on Win 7. I wonder if it is SAS.

Comment: OK, into the nitty gritty then:

HDD: 1.0TB SATA WD10EADS
Destination:
W7 PC, MB=ASUS P5N-T Deluxe, previously only one SATA drive installed out of 6 maximum

Nothing too eccentric.  The Windows PC does see the drive as a functioning hardware device, I just can't find a way to see a volume on it.  I was thinking there might be a command line option to manually mount the drive or something similar.

Comment: What does Disk Management show?

Answer (score 0):

After much wailing and gnashing of teeth it turns out the drives needed to be imported as foreign content (in disk management).  In hindsite the solution was relatively simple, but most problems are when you know the solution :)  Thanks for the input, it led me to the cure.